# How to call REST full API by providing headers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am quite new to Swift,
we have a API server where we need to pass HEADERS like this:

> Content-Type:application/json
>
> Session:fb4e7f9b-0f31-4709-

I was looking in Google, the most basic example uses HTTP url call (i.e GET,POST)
Do I need to use some third-party product to call REST API by providing headers?

I would appreciate if you provide some guideline and possibly some example articles where it's showing how do to REST API call by providing different type HEADERs.

Comment: When posting, please make an effort to spell check your post, format it, use correct grammar, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using Alamofire it's pretty simple.

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Session": "fb4e7f9b-0f31-4709-"
]

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/headers", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
   //Parse or print your response.
}
```

By using `urlRequest`

```
let header: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Session": "fb4e7f9b-0f31-4709-"
]
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "your request url goes here."), cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)
urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = header
urlRequest.httpMethod = //.get, .post, .put
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else if let data = data ,let responseCode = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                do {
                  // Parse your response here.
                   }
                }
                catch let parseJSONError {
                    print("error on parsing request to JSON : \(parseJSONError)")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
```

Answer (score 3):

```swift
import Foundation

let url = URL(string: "")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Session": "fb4e7f9b-0f31-4709-"
]

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
  guard error == nil else { return }
  guard let data = data, let response = response else { return }
  // handle data
}.resume()
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`URLRequest` type documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest) outlines all of the different properties you can set. You need to create a `URLRequest` instance and then use `URLSession` to perform the request.

Answer (score 2):

> with header fields

```
static func getFeed(Completion:@escaping(FeedElement)->Void)
    {
        let urlString = NSString(format: "https://api-nhdev.india.com/api/v1/feeds/1/10/Kondapur") as String
        
        guard let url = URL(string:urlString)
         else {
             return
        }
        
        let header: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": YOUR_AUTH_ID
        ]
        
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = header
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            let session = URLSession.shared

            let mData = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                guard let dataResponse = data,
                    error == nil else {
                        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                        return }
                do{
                    //here dataResponse received from a network request
                 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                 let codabledata = try decoder.decode(FeedElement.self, from: dataResponse)
                    print(codabledata)
                 //Response result
                 Completion(codabledata)
                    
                } catch let parsingError {
                    print("Error", parsingError)
                }
            }
            mData.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension URL
{
    init(baseUrl: String, path: String, method: RequestMethod, params: [String:Any])
    {
        var components = URLComponents(string: baseUrl)!
        components.path += path
        
        switch method {
        case .get,.delete:
            var queryItems = components.queryItems ?? []
            queryItems.append(contentsOf: params.map {
                URLQueryItem(name: $0.key, value: String(describing: $0.value))
            })
            //print(queryItems)
            components.queryItems = queryItems
        default:
            break
        }
        //print(components.url!)
        self = components.url!
        
    }
}

extension URLRequest
{
    init(baseUrl: String, path: String, method: RequestMethod, params: [String:Any]) {
        let url = URL(baseUrl: baseUrl, path: path, method: method, params: params)
        
        //////////////My Code For Remove Percentages In URL//////////////////////////
        let urlWithPath = url.absoluteString.removingPercentEncoding
        let absoluteUrl = URL(string: urlWithPath!)!
        self.init(url: absoluteUrl)
        
        //self.init(url: url)
        let util = AuthToken.shared()
        httpMethod = method.rawValue
        setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        if util.getToken() != "" {
            setValue(util.getToken(), forHTTPHeaderField: "Token")
        }
        
        switch method {
        case .post, .put:
            httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

struct NetworkManager {
    static let environment : NetworkEnvironment = .qa
    private init(){}
    static let shared = NetworkManager();
    private var baseURL = APIEndPoint.baseURL
    
    func load(path:String, method:RequestMethod, params:[String:Any], completion:@escaping(_ responseObject:Data?, _ error:Error?, _ isSuccess: Bool?) -> Void) -> Void{
        
        let reachability = Reachability()
        if(reachability?.connection == .wifi || reachability?.connection == .cellular)
        {
            // Creating the URLRequest object
            let request = URLRequest(baseUrl: baseURL, path: path, method: method, params: params)
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
                (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil
                {
                    completion(nil, nil, false)
                }
                else
                {
                    completion(data, nil, true)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
        else
        {
            completion(nil, nil, false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // MARK: -  get user list
    func getUserList(param : [String:Any]) {
        
        NetworkManager.shared.load(path: APIEndPoint.homeURL, method: .get, params: param) { (data, error, response) in
            
            if response!
            {
                guard let responseData = data else {
                    return
                }
                do {
                    print(responseData)
                    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: .mutableContainers)
                    print(jsonData)
                    let apiResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: responseData)
                    self.userList = apiResponse
                    self.delegate?.getUserListCompleted()
                    
                }catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// MARK : Declare base URL
enum NetworkEnvironment {
    case qa
    case production
}

class APIEndPoint {
    // MARK : Returning base URL
    static var environmentBaseURL : String {
        switch NetworkManager.environment {
        case .production: return ""
        case .qa: return "https://www.jsonkeeper.com/"
        }
    }
        
    // MARK : Finally seted base URL for the end point
    static var baseURL: String {
        return environmentBaseURL
    }
    
    // MARK : List of sub URLs
    static let homeURL = "b/12D8"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import SystemConfiguration
import Foundation

public enum ReachabilityError: Error {
    case FailedToCreateWithAddress(sockaddr_in)
    case FailedToCreateWithHostname(String)
    case UnableToSetCallback
    case UnableToSetDispatchQueue
    case UnableToGetInitialFlags
}

@available(*, unavailable, renamed: "Notification.Name.reachabilityChanged")
public let ReachabilityChangedNotification = NSNotification.Name("ReachabilityChangedNotification")

public extension Notification.Name {
    static let reachabilityChanged = Notification.Name("reachabilityChanged")
}

public class Reachability {
    
    public typealias NetworkReachable = (Reachability) -> ()
    public typealias NetworkUnreachable = (Reachability) -> ()
    
    @available(*, unavailable, renamed: "Connection")
    public enum NetworkStatus: CustomStringConvertible {
        case notReachable, reachableViaWiFi, reachableViaWWAN
        public var description: String {
            switch self {
            case .reachableViaWWAN: return "Cellular"
            case .reachableViaWiFi: return "WiFi"
            case .notReachable: return "No Connection"
            }
        }
    }
    
    public enum Connection: CustomStringConvertible {
        case none, wifi, cellular
        public var description: String {
            switch self {
            case .cellular: return "Cellular"
            case .wifi: return "WiFi"
            case .none: return "No Connection"
            }
        }
    }
    
    public var whenReachable: NetworkReachable?
    public var whenUnreachable: NetworkUnreachable?
    
    @available(*, deprecated, renamed: "allowsCellularConnection")
    public let reachableOnWWAN: Bool = true
    
    /// Set to `false` to force Reachability.connection to .none when on cellular connection (default value `true`)
    public var allowsCellularConnection: Bool
    
    // The notification center on which "reachability changed" events are being posted
    public var notificationCenter: NotificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    
    @available(*, deprecated, renamed: "connection.description")
    public var currentReachabilityString: String {
        return "\(connection)"
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable, renamed: "connection")
    public var currentReachabilityStatus: Connection {
        return connection
    }
    
    public var connection: Connection {
        if flags == nil {
            try? setReachabilityFlags()
        }
        
        switch flags?.connection {
        case .none?, nil: return .none
        case .cellular?: return allowsCellularConnection ? .cellular : .none
        case .wifi?: return .wifi
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate var isRunningOnDevice: Bool = {
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        return false
#else
        return true
#endif
    }()
    
    fileprivate var notifierRunning = false
    fileprivate let reachabilityRef: SCNetworkReachability
    fileprivate let reachabilitySerialQueue: DispatchQueue
    fileprivate(set) var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags? {
        didSet {
            guard flags != oldValue else { return }
            reachabilityChanged()
        }
    }
    
    required public init(reachabilityRef: SCNetworkReachability, queueQoS: DispatchQoS = .default, targetQueue: DispatchQueue? = nil) {
        self.allowsCellularConnection = true
        self.reachabilityRef = reachabilityRef
        self.reachabilitySerialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "uk.co.ashleymills.reachability", qos: queueQoS, target: targetQueue)
    }
    
    public convenience init?(hostname: String, queueQoS: DispatchQoS = .default, targetQueue: DispatchQueue? = nil) {
        guard let ref = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, hostname) else { return nil }
        self.init(reachabilityRef: ref, queueQoS: queueQoS, targetQueue: targetQueue)
    }
    
    public convenience init?(queueQoS: DispatchQoS = .default, targetQueue: DispatchQueue? = nil) {
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr()
        zeroAddress.sa_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr>.size)
        zeroAddress.sa_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
        
        guard let ref = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, &zeroAddress) else { return nil }
        
        self.init(reachabilityRef: ref, queueQoS: queueQoS, targetQueue: targetQueue)
    }
    
    deinit {
        stopNotifier()
    }
}

public extension Reachability {
    
    // MARK: - *** Notifier methods ***
    func startNotifier() throws {
        guard !notifierRunning else { return }
        
        let callback: SCNetworkReachabilityCallBack = { (reachability, flags, info) in
            guard let info = info else { return }
            
            let reachability = Unmanaged<Reachability>.fromOpaque(info).takeUnretainedValue()
            reachability.flags = flags
        }
        
        var context = SCNetworkReachabilityContext(version: 0, info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
        context.info = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged<Reachability>.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
        if !SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef, callback, &context) {
            stopNotifier()
            throw ReachabilityError.UnableToSetCallback
        }
        
        if !SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue(reachabilityRef, reachabilitySerialQueue) {
            stopNotifier()
            throw ReachabilityError.UnableToSetDispatchQueue
        }
        
        // Perform an initial check
        try setReachabilityFlags()
        
        notifierRunning = true
    }
    
    func stopNotifier() {
        defer { notifierRunning = false }
        
        SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef, nil, nil)
        SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue(reachabilityRef, nil)
    }
    
    // MARK: - *** Connection test methods ***
    @available(*, deprecated, message: "Please use `connection != .none`")
    var isReachable: Bool {
        return connection != .none
    }
    
    @available(*, deprecated, message: "Please use `connection == .cellular`")
    var isReachableViaWWAN: Bool {
        // Check we're not on the simulator, we're REACHABLE and check we're on WWAN
        return connection == .cellular
    }
    
    @available(*, deprecated, message: "Please use `connection == .wifi`")
    var isReachableViaWiFi: Bool {
        return connection == .wifi
    }
    
    var description: String {
        guard let flags = flags else { return "unavailable flags" }
        let W = isRunningOnDevice ? (flags.isOnWWANFlagSet ? "W" : "-") : "X"
        let R = flags.isReachableFlagSet ? "R" : "-"
        let c = flags.isConnectionRequiredFlagSet ? "c" : "-"
        let t = flags.isTransientConnectionFlagSet ? "t" : "-"
        let i = flags.isInterventionRequiredFlagSet ? "i" : "-"
        let C = flags.isConnectionOnTrafficFlagSet ? "C" : "-"
        let D = flags.isConnectionOnDemandFlagSet ? "D" : "-"
        let l = flags.isLocalAddressFlagSet ? "l" : "-"
        let d = flags.isDirectFlagSet ? "d" : "-"
        
        return "\(W)\(R) \(c)\(t)\(i)\(C)\(D)\(l)\(d)"
    }
}

fileprivate extension Reachability {
    
    func setReachabilityFlags() throws {
        try reachabilitySerialQueue.sync { [unowned self] in
            var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
            if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(self.reachabilityRef, &flags) {
                self.stopNotifier()
                throw ReachabilityError.UnableToGetInitialFlags
            }
            
            self.flags = flags
        }
    }
    
    func reachabilityChanged() {
        let block = connection != .none ? whenReachable : whenUnreachable
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            block?(self)
            self.notificationCenter.post(name: .reachabilityChanged, object: self)
        }
    }
}

extension SCNetworkReachabilityFlags {
    
    typealias Connection = Reachability.Connection
    
    var connection: Connection {
        guard isReachableFlagSet else { return .none }
        
        // If we're reachable, but not on an iOS device (i.e. simulator), we must be on WiFi
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        return .wifi
#else
        var connection = Connection.none
        
        if !isConnectionRequiredFlagSet {
            connection = .wifi
        }
        
        if isConnectionOnTrafficOrDemandFlagSet {
            if !isInterventionRequiredFlagSet {
                connection = .wifi
            }
        }
        
        if isOnWWANFlagSet {
            connection = .cellular
        }
        
        return connection
#endif
    }
    
    var isOnWWANFlagSet: Bool {
#if os(iOS)
        return contains(.isWWAN)
#else
        return false
#endif
    }
    var isReachableFlagSet: Bool {
        return contains(.reachable)
    }
    var isConnectionRequiredFlagSet: Bool {
        return contains(.connectionRequired)
    }
    var isInterventionRequiredFlagSet: Bool {
        return contains(.interventionRequired)
    }
    var isConnectionOnTrafficFlagSet: Bool {
        return contains(.connectionOnTraffic)
    }
    var isConnectionOnDemandFlagSet: Bool {
        return contains(.connectionOnDemand)
    }
    var isConnectionOnTrafficOrDemandFlagSet: Bool {
        return !intersection([.connectionOnTraffic, .connectionOnDemand]).isEmpty
    }
    var isTransientConnectionFlagSet: Bool {
        return contains(.transientConnection)
    }
    var isLocalAddressFlagSet: Bool {
        return contains(.isLocalAddress)
    }
    var isDirectFlagSet: Bool {
        return contains(.isDirect)
    }
    var isConnectionRequiredAndTransientFlagSet: Bool {
        return intersection([.connectionRequired, .transientConnection]) == [.connectionRequired, .transientConnection]
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import Foundation

// MARK : Declare API request type
enum RequestMethod: String {
    case get = "GET"
    case post = "POST"
    case put = "PUT"
    case delete = "DELETE"
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?